# Ffmpeg stop read data from streaming from 104 MB

Tags: java, process

**When i launch this command in shell**:
/home/ffmpeg-2.0.1-64bit-static/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/livetv/2ch5h264 -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k -f wav -ss 00:00:00 -t 7200 /home/Data/file.wav

That works, 'the file.wav' will be writen and this has for example +-600MB. (the command worked successfully) I confirmed this file has at least 2 hours of audio.

**My Question:**
When i launch this process on Java with:

```
//Current Java App
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

//Command Process to get data from streaming
String cmdLine = "/home/ffmpeg-2.0.1-64bit-static/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/livetv/2ch5h264 -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k -f wav -ss 00:00:00 -t 7200 /home/Data/file.wav";

//Start the process
proc_ffmpeg = rt.exec(cmdLine);

//Wait to Exit
int exitVal = proc_split.waitFor();
```

**FFmpeg doesn't write beyond +- 104MB in file.wav? In this case my audio file only has +- 10mins.**

Thank you

Comment: In the shell, does it write any log information out as it goes? Perhaps you need to read from stdin/stderr of your new process...

Comment: Yes, in shell the ffmpeg process writes log information. I don't understand why is happen in java...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that ffmpeg is writing log information, and you're not reading it in the Java code. There will be a small buffer between the processes, and when that buffer fills up, ffmpeg will block when it tries to write more log information.

You could use `ProcessBuilder` and call `ProcessBuilder.redirectError`/`ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput`, or you could read from the standard error/output streams in your Java code. Unless you're sure it'll only write to one of them, you should do that in other threads. As a simple example:

```
public class StreamConsumer implements Runnable {
    private final InputStream input;

    public StreamConsumer(InputStream input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                // No-op; we're not interested in the data
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log the error or whatever you want to do. The stream is probably
            // broken now...
        }
    }
}

...

new Thread(new StreamConsumer(proc_ffmpeg.getInputStream())).start();
new Thread(new StreamConsumer(proc_ffmpeg.getErrorStream())).start();
```